# Redirect "http://old.net/category/postname" to "https://new.com/postname"?

Tags: redirect, htaccess

Apologies, for the very long title.

I'd really appreciate any help that anyone can offer with a situation I have currently before I go for the plugin option.

About a month ago I moved my site from:

`http` to `https`

I did the move myself and all went well.

Last night I decided to update the Permalink Structure from:

> /category/postname/

to

> /postname/

This switch went well and the site is running perfectly.

Now what I need to address is all the old URLs indexed in Google.

I have this `.htaccess` file on the .com version of my site:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on 
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

And I'm wondering if there is a modification that could be made to the above to permanently redirect the indexed URLs to there corresponding post on the new blog.

Indexed URLs such as:

> www.oldsite.net/category/postname

are returning a 404.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since your new URLs do not have any `category/` in them, you can redirect every URL that contains this and follows a pattern to your new permalink structure.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^category/(.+)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Change `example.com` to your new website's domain. You can also tweak with the `301` status if you wish.

Now, this

> www.oldsite.net/category/postname

will be redirected to

> www.newsite.com/postname

You can also add the entire URL to the rewrite rule, but since your new domain does not have `/category/`, It might be safe to redirect every link, unless you decide to create a post that its slug is `category`!

Comment: Thanks for the responses and solutions.  I have been giving this a lot of thought today and wondered if my initial approach and the basis of this question was wrong.  Currently the .htaccess file of the https://www.newsite.com redirects the domain to https:.  The .htaccess file on the http://www.oldsite.net redirects all the links pointing to that site to the corresponding page on https://www.newsite.com.  Im wondering if a better approach would be to code the .htaccess file of the Oldsite removing the Category at that level given that Wordpress seems to be handling the links to the new site.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this htaccess rule to redirect any http to https :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Changing the example.com to your domain, of course.

Comment: But the 3rd line of his `.htaccess` file already redirects every request to the SSL version. The problem is that he changed the permalink structure, which takes months to be updated by google.

Comment: Whoops...you're right; missed the third line of his original htaccess. Thanks for the catch.